# How to Delete a Sales Order lines data From SAP B1 Add On using DIAPI C#

Tags: c#, sapb1, sap-business-one-di-api

I want to delete some of the particular lines from a sales order documents Lines part by Add On using c# .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first get the document you want to alter using DocEntry.

You then have to set the line number that needs deletion. See below

```
Documents oDoc = oCompany.GetBusinessObject(SAPbobsCOM.BoObjectTypes.oOrders);
int docEntry = 109;
int lineNum = 2;

// Load your sales orders
if (oDoc.GetByKey(docEntry))
{
    // Go through your line items
    for (int i = 0; i < oDoc.Lines.Count; i++)
    {
        oDoc.Lines.SetCurrentLine(i);
        if (oDoc.Lines.LineNum == lineNum) //Find your line number that you want delete.
        {
            oDoc.Lines.Delete(); //Delete
            break;
        }
    }

    // Update your sales order
    if (oDoc.Update() != 0)
        MessageBox.Show(oCompany.GetLastErrorDescription());
}
```

Comment: This is usefull , its perfectly deletes the data . but which items i am deleting their details automatically comes to Document Discount. is there any solution for this ?

Comment: Please explain more about details coming to discount.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void Delete_Single_Line_Row(string docentry, int lNum)
        {
            SAPbobsCOM.Documents oSalesOrd = null;
            oSalesOrd = (SAPbobsCOM.Documents)SBOC_SAP.G_DI_Company.GetBusinessObject(SAPbobsCOM.BoObjectTypes.oOrders);
            int docEntry = Convert.ToInt32(docentry);
            int lineNum = lNum;

            // Load your sales orders
            if (oSalesOrd.GetByKey(docEntry))
            {
                // Go through your line items
                for (int i = 0; i < oSalesOrd.Lines.Count; i++)
                {
                    oSalesOrd.Lines.SetCurrentLine(i);
                    if (oSalesOrd.Lines.LineNum == lineNum) //Find your line number that you want delete.
                    {
                        oSalesOrd.Lines.Delete(); //Delete
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // Update your sales order
                int result = oSalesOrd.Update();

            }
        }    enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Documents oDoc = Utils.oCompany.GetBusinessObject(BoObjectTypes.oOrders);
oDoc.GetByKey(123);
oDoc.Lines.SetCurrentLine(0);
oDoc.Lines.Delete();
int lret = oDoc.Update();
if (lret != 0)
{
    //HANDLE ERROR
}
```

This is pretty straight forward I think.

Comment: This deletes only one single line. how can i delete more lines which i want ?